# In ruby, why does my IRB interactive debugging session always say "No sourcefile available"

Tags: ruby

Just trying to get my irb sessions to actually list the current line of code, and those around it.  Similar to what Perl's -d debugging mode lets you ddo.

Comment: Can you be more clear please?

Comment: Yes, specify which commandline are you using at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a Ruby debugger you could try [ruby-debug](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/ruby-debug.html). It lets you set a breakpoint and then step through the code while displaying a context around the current instruction.

Answer (score 2):

Its because, when you are doing it interactively, your "sourcefile" is std-in.

Comment: this also explains the message when running rdb within `shef` in recipe mode