# Why does my rdebug session say "*** No sourcefile available"

Tags: ruby, thin, rdebug

I'm not sure what the pattern of behaviour is but some programs - notably simple rack.ru based ones running in thin - can't easily be debugged. When a breakpoint is tripped, no source is available

Note this isn't the same as this other S.O. [issue][1]

[1]: [In ruby, why does my IRB interactive debugging session always say "No sourcefile available"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323010/in-ruby-why-does-my-irb-interactive-debugging-) session-always-say-no-sourcefile

Answer (score 7):

err, actually found the source of the problem. I had a `Dir.chdir` buried in my code. Any debugger call after that couldn't find the source, a call before worked fine.

Hopefully that helps somebody at some time.